# how to add and get items from an array in vue3?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

so I am build a shop with a cart in it and I want to add products to the cart and view them in the cart after I added them. how can I fix my code? as I stumbled across the push method of JavaScript but for some reason it does not work for me. so, how can I add items to the cart and retrieve them later?

here is my code:

shop.vue

```
    <template>
    <div class="shop">
        <h1>shop</h1>
        <div class="products" v-for="item in items" :key="item.id">{{ item.name }}</div>
        <button @click="addToCart">Add to Cart</button>
    </div>
    <div class="cart">
        <h1>cart</h1>
        <div class="cartitems" v-for="item in cart" :key="item.id">{{ item.name }} {{ item.price }}</div>
    </div>
</template>
<script>
import Products from "../db.json"

export default {
    name: "shop",
    data() {
        return {
            items: Products,
            cart: []
        }
    },
    methods: {
        addToCart() {
            this.cart.push(this.items.id)
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

db.json as my "db" with the products

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "iphone",
    "price": 2000
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "galaxy",
    "price": 3000
  }
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
addToCart() {
  this.cart.push(this.items.id)
}
```

1. There is a typo (I assume). You want to add a certain item id to the cart. `this.items` is an array and does not have an id property.
2. You actually want to pass the id as an argument to the `addToCart` method:

   `<button @click="addToCart(item.id)">Add to Cart</button>`

Then grab and add it to the cart:

```
    addToCart(id) {
      this.cart.push(id)
    }
```

Update/ Edit:

You also need to place the `<button>` inside the v-for loop, otherwise it will not have access to the iteration scope:

```
     <div class="products" v-for="item in items" :key="item.id">   
        {{ item.name }}
        <button @click="addToCart(item.id)">Add to Cart</button>
     </div>
```

Comment: it does not work. im getting: shop.vue:9 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'id')

Comment: @kikidoyouloveme Interesting :). item.name gets displayed? This should not be an issue, but try also `@click="() => addToCart(item.id)"`

Comment: Just realized your button is placed outside the v-for loop. My bad. I updated my answer

Comment: still not working. same error...

Comment: ok so after your update i think is working but i have 2 buttons of addtocart and how can i get those items after i added them to the cart in the cart?

Comment: You usually want to be able to add products to the cart individually. With only one button in place for the whole list, what would it be adding to the cart? You would need to make the products list selectable, which is a different approach. Although it will eventually lead to the same result, the general UI/ UX approach here is not completely clear to me. 
As to the question on how to render contents in the cart, you should consult the official docs a bit more and make sure you really understand Vues basic concepts.